# std::ofstream doesn't work with short enums in C++Builder 10.3

Tags: c++, c++builder, access-violation, ofstream, short

If I set "Short enums" to **true** ([Project -> Options -> C++ Compiler](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/C%2B%2B_Compiler)), I receive an Access Violation in return from a function where `std::ofstream` is used.

Example code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

void __fastcall TForm1::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{
    AnsiString textFile = "err.txt";
    std::ofstream out;
    out.open(textFile.c_str());
    out << textFile.c_str();
    out.close();
}
```

Does anyone know how to use short enums and still work with `std::ofstream`?

PS it's legacy code and I can't change the size of every enum in the project like
`enum MyEnum : byte`.

Comment: Are you using the classic compiler perhaps? I recommend using the clang-enhanced compiler instead.

Comment: On an unrelated note, DO NOT use the Form's OnCreate event in C++. It is a Delphi idiom that can produce **undefined behavior** in C++. Use the Form's actual constructor instead. Same with the OnDestroy event, use the destructor instead.

Comment: @TedLyngmo The "Short enum" option applies to multiple compilers, not just the classic compiler.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, it was more of a general recommendation. I wouldn't be surprised if short enums in the classic compiler is implemented using the c++11 feature to specify the underlying type which is marked with "_The Classic compiler is not recommended: instead it is recommend you use the Clang-enhanced compilers_" at Embarcadero's site.

Comment: @TedLyngmo "*I wouldn't be surprised if short enums in the classic compiler is implemented using the C++11 feature to specify the underlying type*" - the classic compiler does not support C++11.

Comment: @RemyLebeau No, but they have added some C++11 features to it, like scoped enums etc.

Comment: @TedLyngmo perhaps so, but this is not one of those cases. The short enums feature existed for a long time before C++11, and the core architecture of the classic compiler was not changed when C++11 came along. And this is easy to see by the fact that the short enums feature only affects enums that don't explicitly specify an underlying type in code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Aha, I see.

Comment: @ Ted Lyngmo, I use 64bit application for windows, and havent options to change my compiler, so probably it's clang.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau ok, I will keep it in mind (about OnCreate), but this problem not related with OnCreate

Comment: @user3575468 You say it's a legacy project. Are all things that may be affected by the "short enums" setting recompiled? I'm thinking that there may be some component / object file that is used which was compiled with that setting "off".

Comment: @Remy Lebeau  - you say it is unsafe to use the form OnCreate event. I do recall  (in CB6) that this did used to get called before the class constructor. But I've just tried an expt using 10.4.2 (with the "classic" compiler to Win32) and put breakpoints in each event and found that the start up sequence is  Constructor, FormCreate, FormShow, FormActivate and the close down sequence is FormClose, FormHide, FormDestroy, Destructor. I would have thought this meant that is is OK to put code in the FormCreate event handler.....

Comment: @RogerCigol the order is determined by the Form's [`OldCreateOrder`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TForm.OldCreateOrder) property, which is false by default, but has been known in the past to randomly flip to true, thus changing the order. Both orders are valid in Delphi, but the `OldCreateOrder=true` order is Undefined Behavior in C++. Which is why I think the events are too dangerous to use in C++. Besides, the events are against the design principles of C++ OOP anyway, encouraging init/cleanup to occur outside of the normal construction/destruction sequence.